# swift show up window programmatically

Tags: popup, swift2, command-line-tool

Im writing on a command line tool that shows a pop up window.
Of course programmatically.

In this pop up window I show two text fields, one for the username and the other for password. But when I try to type text in one of them, it wont work. I can select the textField and everything but when I try to type text it wont show up

Can anyone help me please

**Edit:**

Here's the code:

main.swift:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

let app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
let con = TestApplicationController()

app.delegate = con
app.run()
```

window.swift:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

final class TestApplicationController: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let window1 = NSWindow()
    let view = NSView()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    window1.setFrame(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 443, height: 229), display: true)
    window1.contentView = view
    window1.opaque = false
    window1.center()
    window1.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    window1.title = "Finder"
    window1.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.MaximumWindowLevelKey))
    window1.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)

    // MARK: - Name Label
    let nameLabel: NSTextField = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(138, 101, 44, 17))
    nameLabel.editable = false
    nameLabel.drawsBackground = false
    nameLabel.bezeled = false
    nameLabel.selectable = false
    nameLabel.stringValue = "Name:"

    windowContentView.addSubview(nameLabel)

    // MARK: - Password Label
    let passwordLabel: NSTextField = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(118, 69, 64, 17))
    passwordLabel.editable = false
    passwordLabel.drawsBackground = false
    passwordLabel.bezeled = false
    passwordLabel.selectable = false
    passwordLabel.stringValue = "Passwort:"

    windowContentView.addSubview(passwordLabel)

    // MARK: - Name Field
    let nameField: NSTextField = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(190, 98, 233, 22))
    nameField.editable = true
    nameField.selectable = true
    nameField.stringValue = "Michael"
    nameField.action = "nameEdited:"

    windowContentView.addSubview(nameField)

    // MARK: - Password Field
    let passwordField: NSSecureTextField = NSSecureTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(190, 66, 233, 22))
    passwordField.editable = true
    passwordField.selectable = true
    passwordField.stringValue = ""
    passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
    passwordField.action = "passwordEdited:"

    windowContentView.addSubview(passwordField)

    func nameEdited(sender: NSTextField){
        print("editedname")
    }

    func passwordEdited(sender: NSTextField){
        print("editedpw")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: I have added the code from the project. Simple past it into a new command line tool project and it should work

Comment: I assume when you type the password nothing show up. In Linux the password won't show up. For example open the terminal and try su root and press enter and it will ask for password then any thing it won't show up.

Comment: No thats not right. I know what you mean but in my case I cant type anything in the username and password textfield. I think the problem is that there are 2 windows in foreground at the same time. So when I try to type something into the textfield instead I type into the second window that is open. Try it with Xcode for example.